# Is aggregating points to areal units ever useful - Spatial statistics

Tags: spatial-statistics, gis-principle, autocorrelation, aggregation

I have a large point dataset of a population (By population, I mean that it was not a sample e.g. all houses in a county with an attribute such as size, price, age, etc.). Each point represents each case, their accurate position in space. It is possible to aggregate them up to any geographical unit such as census block, census tract, zip code etc. I would like to conduct several spatial statistical analyses (autocorrelation etc.) on this data. I tend to think that I should keep the data in the current format to maintain maximum variability rather than aggregating it to a spatial unit (e.g. census tract) to avoid MAUP and loss of variability.

However, is there ever a case to be made that under certain conditions a set of **population** point data should be aggregated to an areal unit?

Comment: To be clear: each point represents a settlement (town) and has a population value?

Comment: Also, do you have appropriate areal units for each point?

Comment: Each point represents each case, their accurate position in space. By population, I meant that it was not a sample. E.g. all houses in a county (with an attribute such as size, price, age, etc.). It is possible to aggregate them up to any geographical unit such as census block, census tract, zip code etc.

Comment: I suggest you edit that new info into the question.

Comment: In general, computing statistics for data that is "aggregated up" will give you information about those aggregations (i.e. information about census blocks) rather than information about the individual points and their relationships.

That said, this type of a question may be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).